# How to replace text by javascript with other text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert

```
<images src="vendor/chessboard.js/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wR" style="width: 67px;height: 67px;"></images>
```

this text into

```
<img src="vendor/chessboard.js/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wR" style="width: 67px;height: 67px;" />
```

How can i do so ???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I want to know what will be the regexp.

Comment: So what exactly did you try?

Comment: I'm trying to make first <images into <img and last </images> into nothing.

Comment: Show us some code. I do understand your task

Answer (score 0):

You can use sites [like this one](https://regex101.com/) to come up with the regex flavor you are after

```
//Switch <images to <img
var pattern = /<images/gi;//declare your regex pattern
var originString = '<images src="asdf">';//the string to go against
console.log(originString);//show the string as is before modding it
console.log(originString.replace(pattern, "<img"));//show the modded string

//remove </images>
var pattern2 = /<\/images>/gi;
var originString2 = '<img src="blahblah"></images>';
console.log(originString2);
console.log(originString2.replace(pattern2, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to transform `<images` and `></images>` occurrences into `<img` and `/>` respectively:

```js
const text = '<images src="vendor/chessboard.js/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png" alt="" class="piece-417db" data-piece="wR" style="width: 67px;height: 67px;"></images>';

const result = text.replace(/<images/gi, '<img').replace(/><\/images>/gi, '/>');

console.log(result); // -> <img ... />
```